# embedded Spring Boot profile leaving elements after profile overridden on command line

Tags: spring-boot

We have a jar with a local profile embedded at build.
`application.yml` explicitly sets `spring.profiles.active` as `local`.
`application-local.yml` defines `kafka.topic.bootstrapservers`, then `kafka.topic.consumer.configs.enable-admin-port-consumer.bootstrapserver` as a port on `localhost`.

The jar is run with `-Dspring.profiles.active=sit`. The `sit` profile loads, but it still tries to reach kafka on `localhost`, which is only in the embedded `application-local.yml`.

It's a merge, yes? `application.yml` invokes `local`, the command line merges `sit`. Values in common use `sit`, but fields only in `local` are left active.

Can someone who knows the underlying mechanics confirm or correct?

Comment: it is a merge kind of. `application.yml` is always included as it is not dependent on any spring profile, which then in your case includes local profile and additionally you set sit.

Comment: pero_hero is right.  
If you mention more than one profile, they apparently accumulate rather than  overwriting as you might expect.
Is there a way to remove a profile once mentioned? I think not... We made them fix the yaml.